# Woocommerce Product attribute not imported with wordpress Importer

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, customization

I used the WordPress Importer plugin and successfully imported all content but  woocommerce product attributes are not imported. Tried a few different tests, and few different servers. Same result.

```
Here is an example of an error received after attempting to import:

Failed to import pa_color Blue
Failed to import pa_color Brown
Failed to import pa_size Large
Failed to import pa_size Medium

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks
```

Comment: The problem is, that you would need a specific importer that would import all the data that is not in the standard WordPress set. This is very plugin specific. Do you have a map of all the data that is saved by WooCommerce and where it is saved? If so, please update your question with an [edit] and we can reopen it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress default importer will not work for WooCommerce product attributes. There is a plugin available to import WooCommerce products which handles import for products as well as their attributes. I'll not paste the plugin URL here since it's a third party plugin, but if you google for 'WooCommerce import', you will easily get that plugin.